# Passing Java String with multiple lines to a javascript function ( using Velocity)

Tags: java, javascript, arguments, velocity

I'm trying to pass a String variable into my javascript function, but my variable has a multiple lines: For example :

```
String info = "aaaa \n bbb \n ccc";
```

I need this form to properly display it. And now I have a "result" Java Object with info field and I can't pass this to my javascript function.

```
popupErrors('$!{result.info}')"
```

The problem is that result.info is put here as a whole text with new lines. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: without knowing what popuperror does it would be hard to help.

Comment: Do you want your `\n`s to be converted to `<br>`s?

Comment: That would be a good idea to convert it to a <br>s. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe popupErrors is displaying the string an an HTML popup instead of say a javascript alert. So the new lines are not getting show, you'd need to replace `\n` with `<br/>` so they show up in HTML.
OR
Maybe `$!{result.info}` is automatically HTML encoding your `\n` to `&#010;`

Comment: Changing \n to <br/> in my Java class resolved my problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to [escape the string to Javascript format](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html#javascript%28%29):

```
popupErrors('$esc.javascript($result.info)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your String so that all the JavaScript special characters (end of line, ", ', tabs, etc.) are escaped (\n, \", \', \t, etc.).

Commons-lang has [StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript%28java.lang.String%29) to do this. Encapsulate this method inside a JSP tag, or escape the string in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

replace \n with space.

```
Str.replace("\n"," ");
```

Then pass the string to javascript function

Comment: This won't work if there is comment "//" inside your string